# How to use gherkin language in ThoughtWorks Twist framework?

Tags: .net, bdd, ui-automation, gherkin, twist

I am doing BDD. I am working on Visual Studio 2010 - C#. I looked over internet for gherkin-twist integration but I got no solution. Please suggest me how to use gherkin language in ThoughtWorks Twist framework.

Please also suggest me recommended readings for Twist and gherkin.

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario page you can write down the gherkin stuffs as described [here](http://support.thoughtworks.com/entries/21663498-Getting-started-with-Twist). The corresponding code can be implemented either by manual or using the record option.